# How to execute operations for a batch of elements in ArrayList with CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

Java version : 11

I have List of objects, I want to perform certain operations on them, where one operations depends on the result of another.
To achieve this workflow in Async fashion, I am using `CompletableFuture`.

Currently I am doing this by partitioning the List into sub lists and giving each of the sub list to `CompletableFuture`, so each thread in my thread-pool can start working on that sublist.

The code for above approach I used and **working** is :

```
List<SomeObject> someObjectList // original list

List<List<SomeObject>> partitionList = ListUtils.partition(someObjectList, partionSize);

partitionList.forEach(subList -> {
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->  firstOperation(subList), executorService)
            .thenAcceptAsync(firstOpresult -> secondOperationWithFirstOpResult(firstOpresult),executorService);
});

public static List<String> firstOperation(List<SomeObject> subList){
        //perform operation
        return List<String>;
}

public static void secondOperationWithFirstOpResult(List<String> firstOpProducedList) {
        //perform operation
        //print results.
}
```

Here the problem is partitioning the original list,

> because if my original list has 100 thousand records and partion size
> is say 100(which means I want 100 items in each sublist), I will have
> 1000 sublist objects each holding 100 elements, which may not be good considering this many objects in memory, moreover if the partion size is user controlled/config controller, a smaller partion size would result in huge no of sublist objects.

instead of partitioning the original list,

1. I want to take the original list.(say 100 elements)
2. Have a startIndex and endIndex on the original list(say 0 to 9, 10 to 19...)
3. And give each of those batches to a thread, in threadpool with CompletableFuture
4. So this thread can perform the two operations.

I know SO is not place for exact solution, but if you could nudge me in the right direction, a pseudo code or even if this is possible with `CompletableFuture` in the first place, would be great help :)

Comment: The different stages of a CompletableFuture could be executed on different threads. Why do you want one thread to do both operations?

Comment: Also this looks like a great use case for a [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). Did you already have a look at that? You could have each thread take their batch of the original list and then do the two operations on the elements.

Comment: @user7, yes it's ok even if it's not a single thread, but my main concern is creating batches and giving them to thread/s.

Comment: @Lino, I have updated my question for more details on why I want to avoid partitioning and go for batching on ArrayList. I will check on ForkJoinPool.

Comment: `[..]which may not be good considering this many objects in memory` - Can't say without measuring performance. Depending on what implementation of subList you use, you can just create a view over the original list and not actually copy the list elements. One example is [Google Guava partition](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-). And `List#subList` also returns a view of the portion of the backing list

Comment: @NishikantTayade I've thrown together a small example using a `ForkJoinPool`: https://ideone.com/1UiFJM, maybe this can help you. Let me know if it doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `ListUtils.partition` is not a standard method, it’s impossible to say, how it works. But if it works “the smart way”, it will use [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) on the original list, instead of copying data.

If you want to be on the safe side, you can do the trivial partitioning yourself:

```java
IntStream.range(0, (someObjectList.size() + partionSize - 1) / partionSize)
    .forEach(p -> {
        int start = p * partionSize,
            end = Math.min(someObjectList.size(), start + partionSize);
        List<SomeObject> subList = someObjectList.subList(start, end);
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->  firstOperation(subList), executorService)
            .thenAcceptAsync(r -> secondOperationWithFirstOpResult(r), executorService);
    });
```

Since these sublists do not store the elements, they consume less memory than the `CompletableFuture` instances, for example. So this is nothing to worry about.

But if you can live with using the default thread pool¹ instead of `executorService`, you could use

```java
IntStream.range(0, (someObjectList.size() + partionSize - 1) / partionSize)
    .parallel()
    .forEach(p -> {
        int start = p * partionSize,
            end = Math.min(someObjectList.size(), start + partionSize);
        List<SomeObject> subList = someObjectList.subList(start, end);
        secondOperationWithFirstOpResult(firstOperation(subList));
    });
```

where each sublist only exists while being processed.

This will already use Fork/Join tasks under the hood. There is no need to implement those Fork/Join operations yourself.

¹ the default pool is unspecified, but will be [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) in practice.

Comment: @Holger, ```ListUtils.partition()``` in my code, is from Apache Commons IO, which documentation says ```The inner lists are sublist views of the original list, produced on demand using List.subList(int, int), and are subject to all the usual caveats about modification as explained in that API.```, I guess this what you meant when you said smart enough right ? Same has been pointed out by @user7

Comment: @NishikantTayade exactly. This means, you could also stay with the original code, if you want.

Comment: @Holger ```[], they consume less memory than the CompletableFuture instances```, can you explain this just a bit more ? I got the first part that as sublist is just a view, its more efficient, but ```less memory than the CompletableFuture instances``` this statement I did not get

Comment: This was only meant to remind you that there are costs you might not even think about, because they’re negligible in most cases, and the sublist view is even below that bar. A completable future has to track its completion status and the dependent actions, then, the actual job is encapsulated in another object that is submitted to an executor service. That’s all not much in total, it’s just that a sublist is even less (in most cases, it actually depends on the particular list implementation from which it was derived).